# What is the best way to calculate the difference in format hh:mm:ss from a date to end of date?

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date in the format `2019-10-11 16:47:44.042` and 
I need to calculate the diff to end of the day.

For example :07:12:24

What is the best way to do this calculation with SQL (in Snowflake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calculate the next date by dateadd, and then use datediff to find the seconds to next day, and convert the result to timestamp.

```
set t = to_timestamp('2019-10-11 16:47:44.042');

select to_varchar( to_timestamp( DATEDIFF('ms', $t,  dateadd( 'day',1,  date_trunc('DAY', $t )) ) / 1000 ), 'HH24:MI:SS.FF3');
```

Dividing to 1000 is a trick that you can not find anywhere else! :)

You can create a function based on the above formula:

```
create or replace function timetoendofday ( t timestamp )
returns varchar
as 'select to_varchar( to_timestamp( DATEDIFF(''ms'', t, dateadd( ''day'',1,  date_trunc(''DAY'', t )) ) / 1000 ), ''HH24:MI:SS.FF3'')';
```

Now it's simple to use:

```
select timetoendofday( '2019-10-11 16:47:44.042' );
-- returns 07:12:15.958
```

Comment: I missed the format!!! So my method provides full timestamp including ms :(

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! It works like a magic

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate time difference in seconds between your timestamp and beginning of next day, then cast it to timestamp and time to have it in readable format like that:

```
with tab as(
  select to_timestamp('2019-10-11 16:47:44.042') ts
)
select to_time(to_timestamp(timediff(second, tab.ts, to_date(tab.ts) + 1)))
from tab
-- returns 07:12:16
```